# xslt forms not working with current Firefox but works perfect with Chrome

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

Has anyone encountered form problems with xsl. I leaving a link only because I don't know how to illustrate incompatibilities otherwise.

With Firefox, the reset or the submit doesn't work, but on Chrome and Explorer it does, though the formatting is off for Explorer it still works.

[This is a working link to my xml file that's creating the problem](http://galzerano.com/clientdata.xml)

Any ideas. Can the xhtml part of Firefox be off? Or is it me?

Thank you...

Comment: You seem to have nested two `form` elements? What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: wow that could be the problem, going to check now

Comment: If you write it up as a solution I'll credit you for it. It worked. It should be against the law to code at 3am, nevertheless Chrome and Explorer figured it out so I didn't think it was a stupid mistake like I made. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two nested `form` elements, as most browsers feed the transformation result to the HTML parser you might get away with that. Mozilla, however, renders the result tree of the XSLT transformation, meaning there is no correction by the HTML parser. That could explain the difference.